# Getting "error: could not amend shell profile: Permission denied" installing rustup using recommended command

Tags: rust, rustup

I tried installing Rust using the below command, which is recommended by https://rustup.rs/ for Unixes:

```
curl --proto '=https' --tlsv1.2 -sSf https://sh.rustup.rs | sh
```

but getting an error

```
error: could not amend shell profile: '/Users/XXXX/.bash_profile'
       could not write rcfile file: '/Users/XXXX/.bash_profile'
       Permission denied (os error 13)
```

However, I am using `zsh` not `bash`.

Comment: We're gonna need more info to give you any meaningful help. For example, what OS are you using?

Comment: "For example, what OS are you using?" I can't help with this question, but surely the title of the question makes the OS clear! (Perhaps it was edited after you asked though?)

Comment: Any reason why you're not using homebrew to install Rust? (via `brew install rustup`)

Comment: @SirDarius I guess because this way of installing rustup is the one that is recommended on https://rustup.rs/

Comment: So, issue 2040 in the rustup repo was about the situation where someone deliberately makes their HOME unwritable, then tries to install software that modifies HOME.

Its not clear whether the OP was doing this:
1) make HOME unwritable
2) export RUSTUP_HOME=...
3) then run the recommended command

or whether they just ran the recommended command and for some reason HOME was unwritable.

If its the former, I think the question is incomplete and misleading and should be edited

@aryan-bagade can you please clarify?

Answer (score 5):

Your home directory seems to not be editable which crashes the installer.

There seems to be a fix for this discussed in a [rustup repo issue](https://github.com/rust-lang/rustup/issues/2040#issuecomment-890798752). Append `-s -- -y --no-modify-path` to `bash`:

```bash
curl --proto '=https' --tlsv1.2 -sSf https://sh.rustup.rs | \
bash -s -- -y --no-modify-path
```

Alternatively, you could give write permission to the path that couldn't be edited, or run this command with `sudo`.